# Way to encode UserID column when training DNN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

If you have large number of users, say 1million performing one-hot encoding will add 1M-1 dimension to original dataset. This seems very inefficient but cannot think of any other way to encode userID.

What is the best practice and why?

Answer (score 0):

There are many other ways of encoding categorical variables, be it high or low cardinality, ordinal or nominal. You can find a list of them [here](https://contrib.scikit-learn.org/category_encoders/).

Usually ID feature is not useful but I don't know about your case. I would say something simple like `OrdinalEncoder` might work as UserID is nothing but a unique ID for each user and using `OrdinalEncoder` will essentially convert the feature into a list of integers thus preserving that information. But take a look at the link I provided and check put all the types of encoders to get a better understanding!

**Cheers!**